# Can turning off a computer while an OS is running damage the RAM

Tags: memory, operating-systems, hardware-failure

The question pretty much says it all. I had a problem with RAM and bought new ones. Theoretically, what else could cause RAM problems that can be avoided?

Comment: Only problems with a memory module can cause memory problems.  If you are asking if shutting the power on any electronic device damage any portion of the electronics then the answer is of course it can.  One of the reasons there is a shutdown procedure.

Comment: As seen from the RAM, there is no difference between "a shutdown procedure" and "turning the power off while the OS is running". The supply voltage goes away, there's nothing exciting, or damaging, about that, and it does not make any difference to the RAM modules what you did before you made the power supply stop supplying power. Data on disk would be another question, with a different answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Shut it off as often as you like, whenever you like, should NEVER affect the RAM.

Avoid static discharge while handing RAM outside the computer. Avoid using the computer as a lighting rod. Don't install or remove RAM with the power on.

Good RAM is trouble-free, or warranteed. Cheesy/counterfeit/whatever RAM perhaps less so, but even there it's usually troublefree (ie, I have seen very little to support paying 10X the price for RAM, but don't mind paying a few dollars more for a known brand/vendor, given the choice)

Comment: I had PNY memory that should have been warranteed, but I got the computer as a refurb on ebay with the RAM included, so no Original purchaser proof.

Comment: I would avoid shutting the power. Of course, it's less possible, but it CAN damage the RAM. And if your RAM wasn't damaged, be sure that you damage the HDD (and make "bad" clusters).

Comment: @Jet If you're arguing with both of the current answers, can you please find a source and make your own answer?

Answer (score 8):

No, turning the computer off while the computer is running will not damage RAM.

However, it can corrupt your data.  Any unwritten data in RAM or cache will not get written to disk and this can cause a loss of data.